# sfdx command for Salesforce Functions is not working

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

When i execute command `sfdx help function` it throws error below

```
»   Error: command function not found
```

I am following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XzaJ0TNwvo

SFDX Version - sfdx-cli/7.105.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.0

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce Functions is not GA. Until the feature becomes GA or you obtain access to a preview program and follow any applicable setup instructions, you won't be able to use that command or follow steps in demo videos.

Clarification: I don't know whether there are any preview programs available at the time of this writing. The situation may have changed if you're reading this answer in the future. Discuss your interest in this feature with your Account Executive.

Comment: Is there a way to get access it using Beta Program?

Comment: I don't know; I don't work on that team. Ask your Account Executive whether there are any programs available to you.

Answer (score 1):

To apply for the Beta, you need to sign up via https://sfdc.co/functions-beta

Once you have been approved, and have access to the feature in your dev hub, you need to follow the steps from the documentation:

[Configure Orgs for Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/config-org.html#enable-functions-on-dev-hub-orgs):

1. Enable Functions on Dev Hub Orgs
2. Create Compute Environment for Org
3. Enable the Functions feature in your scratch org definition file.

and follow the steps outlined in : [Deploy a Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/deploy#connect-salesforce-functions-to-your-org)